# difference between require(__DIR__ . '/file.php') and require('file.php')

Tags: php

As asked in the title, whats the difference between

```
require(__DIR__ . '/file.php')
```

and

```
require('file.php')
```

?

(when both files are in the same folder)

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: One is an absolute path, the other a relative one subject to the current working directory and the `include_path` priorization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do

```
require(__DIR__ . '/file.php')
```

then you are requiring the file with the full pathname. If the file doing this require is required by another file in another directory, this require will always work. On the other hand, if you

```
require('file.php')
```

then if the file where this require statement is is required by another file in another directory, this statement will fail.

That is why it is generally good practice to include the `__DIR__`.